# Iterate through vector contained in another class

Tags: c++, class, vector, iteration

**Program Description**

I have three classes: A, B and C.

For the purpose of this question, Class B simply contains an ID variable, and a state variable, along with setters and getters for those.

Class A contains a vector of B-objects, along with functions to store, delete, modify or compare units using a unit ID.

Class C contains functionality to talk with a black box, this black box contains the same vector of B as Class A, but with updated states.

Rough examples of the classes with basic info is shown at the end of this post.

**Problem**

In my main window I want to iterate through the vector found in Class A. For all the elements I wish to get the ID, pass it to Class C, and have Class C return an updated state. I've drawn a crude [sequence diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJQhL.jpg) to illustrate what I mean.

My issue is how to properly iterate through the vector in Class A, in order to obtain the ID which is then sent to Class C.

What I've considered at this point is something akin to the following(Note: The vector in Class A is automatically populated for the purposes of this question):

```
int main() {
  ...
  ...
  for(int i = 0; i < A.getVectorSize(); i++) {
    char ID = A.getID( i );
    bool state = C.getState( ID );
    A.updateState(ID, state);
  }
}
```

This is not exactly very brilliant, which is why I'm  asking for suggestions on how to perform this task. I've drawn up a rough ["Overview" image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I00fR.jpg) of the system. Apologies for the illegibility of my drawings.

**Classes**

```
class A {
  public:
    void updateStatus(char ID, bool status);
    ...
    ...
  private:
    vector<B> b_Storage;
}

class B {
  public:
    getters & setters
  private:
    char ID;
    bool state;
}

class C {
  public:
    bool getState(char ID);
    ...
  private:
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sounds like there should be a function in A that does this for you.  That way you can work with the vector directly in the function.

Comment: I think it IS brilliant enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could choose to not iterate in `main`, but instead move the iteration into `A`:

```
class A
{
public:
     void updateStates(std::function<bool(char)> f)
     {
          for (const auto& b: b_Storage)
          {
              updateStatus(b.id, f(b.id));
          }
     }
};

// ...

int main() {
    // ...
    A a;
    C c;
    a.updateStates([&](char id) { return C.getState(id); });
}
```

This makes `main` more independent of `A`'s implementation.

Comment: Seems like the most sensible thing.

I'm still quite the novice at c++ programming, so I'm unsure of what happens here:

**a.updateStates([&](char id) -> bool { return C.getState(id); });**

Comment: @trick4GLTE The parameter is a lambda expression; a definition of an anonymous function. You can read about it e.g.  [here](http://www.umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/Lambda.pdf). If you're learning from a reasonably new book (something like 2011 or later), it should cover them.

Comment: Thank you, will try to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is iterating over the elements of `b_Storage`, which is private, you could try using iterators by adding two public methods in class A:

```
std::vector<B>::iterator begin() {
return b_Storage.begin();
}
std::vector<B>::iterator end() {
return b_Storage.end();
}
```

and use those iterators to access the elements of `b_Storage`.